# Groovy vs Java - difference in floating point accuracy

Tags: java, groovy, floating-accuracy

What could be the reason for difference in floating point accuracy here?

```
def "emi test"(){
        given:
        def P =  6000000.00
        def n = 20 * 12
        def r = (8.35/12)/100

        double emi_g = (P * r * (1+r).power(n))  / ((1+r).power(n) - 1)
        double emi_j= (P * r * Math.pow(1+r,n)) / (Math.pow(1+r,n)-1);
        expect:
        emi_g == emi_j
    }
```

result:

```
emi_g == emi_j
|     |  |
|     |  51501.177737160346
|     false
51501.177737160666
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to types.

`(1 + r).power(n) - 1` evaluates to a `BigDecimal`

`P * r * (1 + r).power(n)` evaluates to a `BigDecimal`

`P * r * Math.pow(1 + r, n)` evaluates to a `Double`

`Math.pow(1 + r, n) - 1` evaluates to a `Double`

It isn't clear what your requirements are and whether or not you care about the precision being lost and knowing those requirements would help describe how to get the desired behavior.  The answer to the question as asked...

> What could be the reason for difference in floating point accuracy
>   here?

Is because the expressions evaluate to different types and the rules associated with dividing a `Double` by a `Double` (and the fact that you are the numerator and denominator values are in a `Double` to begin with, as opposed to `BigDecimial`) cause you to lose some precision.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is explained by the data type of the results.

When run in a shell, the types of your results are:

```
groovy:000> emi_g.getClass()
===> class java.math.BigDecimal
groovy:000> emi_j.getClass()
===> class java.lang.Double
```

Groovy's implementation returns a `BigDecimal`, which has better precision than `Double`

Comment: but both are defined as double

Comment: The return type of all `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.power` methods is `Number`

Comment: Here are the rules followed by `DefaultGroovyMethods.power()` to determine the type of the result: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#power_operator

Comment: The way his test is written, neither `emi_g` nor `emi_j` will be either `BigDecimal` or `Double`, they will both be 64 bit primitives.  The issue is that the values on the RHS are of different types and when they are coerced down to the primitive, precision is being lost and the starting values for those RHS's are not the same.